# What is meaning of the term "Sans" in a class name?

Tags: terminology, naming, class

I was reading code of a java project where I found a class name like "UserSansXml". This class is dealing with user objects. I wanted to know the meaning of "sans".

Comment: FWIW, "sans" is the *french* translation of "without".

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it is also a perfectly good English word with the same meaning.

Comment: @jk. thanks to the Normans conquering England in 1066

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'Sans' means 'without'. Think of typefaces like 'Sans-Serif'.

Without context, it's hard to speculate what 'UserSansXml' means.

Comment: User without Xml, obviously :)

Comment: That helps. Reading the code, I figured out, User data comes from xml and later gets stored in db. UserSansXml class deals with the user objects found in xml and the methods in this class has public methods to access users without bothering xml tags.